# How to find date with regular expresions

Tags: python

I have to find some date inside an string with a regular expresions in python

```
astring ='L2A_T21HUB_A023645_20210915T135520'
```

and i'm trying to get the part before the T with shape `xxxxxxxx` where every x is a number.

```
desiredOutput = '20210915'
```

I'm new in regex so I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: The `T135520` afterwords looks like an HHmmss format, so, I think splitting on underscores makes more sense than regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the astring's format is consistent, meaning it will always have the same shape with respect to the date, you can split the string by '_' and get the last substring and get the date from there as such:

```
astring ='L2A_T21HUB_A023645_20210915T135520'
date_split = astring.split("_").  # --> ['L2A', 'T21HUB', 'A023645', '20210915T135520']
desiredOutput = date_split[3][:8] # --> [3] = '20210915T135520' [:8] gets first 8 chars
print(desiredOutput)              # --> 20210915
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted an actual datetime object

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> astring = 'L2A_T21HUB_A023645_20210915T135520'
>>> date_str = astring.split('_')[-1]
>>> datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 15, 13, 55, 20)
```

From  that, you can use `datetime.strftime` to reformat to a new string,  or you can use `split('T')[0]` to get the string you want.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with Regex is that there can be unexpected patterns that match your expected pattern and throw things off. However, if you know that only the date portion will ever have 8 sequential digits, you can do this:

```
import re

date_patt = re.compile('\d{8}')
date = date_patt.search(astring).group(0)
```

You can develop more robust patterns based on your knowledge of the formatting of the incoming strings. For instance, if you know that the date will always follow an underscore, you could use a look-behind assertion:

```
date_patt = re.compile(r'(?<=\_)\d{8}')  # look for '_' before the date, but don't capture
```

Hope this helps. Regex can be finicky and may take some tweaking, but hope this sets you in the right direction.

Comment: Why escape the underscore?

Comment: @OneCricketeer When it comes to regex, some people escape more than they need to as it still works and you don't have to think which symbol characters to escape and which don't need to be escaped + it makes some characters more visible (eg I've seen it often with space - `'\ `' vs `' '`).

Comment: @h4z3 exactly, and without knowing OP's situation, it could be the case that the `A023645` portion of his code occasionally looks like 'A + 8 digits'. In this case, without escaping the underscore, `re.search()` might find that pattern first and return it, despite not being what OP wants. It's a delicate balance between making the pattern broad enough, but not too broad.